# HTML Form IP Address Validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am looking to validate IP addresses on a webpage using jQuery.  There are two small updates I would like some help with.

1. How can I get the `Valid IP` and `Invalid IP` to appear when the
   page loads, not just when the text box is edited.
2. how can I style the text so that `Valid IP` appears in green and `Invalid IP`
   appears in red?

I have created a [JS Fiddle of my work so far](http://jsfiddle.net/r5aeus62/).

Comment: call the function when page load(i.e. document.ready()).. add " .css('color', 'red'); "property to change color.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote on my question?  Seems unfair as its a genuine problem I'm facing.

Comment: Yeah, there is no reason... and i think you are not blaming me.. :(

Comment: @Riad not blaming you at all!  I'm just asking publicly for whoever downvoted it to explain why they did so, so I can learn from this mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I get the Valid IP and Invalid IP to appear when the page loads, not just when the text box is edited.

You can wait until the dom-tree is loaded and then fetch the ip and perform the validation:

```
$(document).on("ready", function()
{
    var ip = getIp(); // The way you implement it.
    validateIpAddress(ip);
});
```

Where your `validateIpAddress` method changes the text according to whether the pattern is valid or not:

```
if (!pattern.test(ip))
{
    $('#validate_ip').text('Not Valid IP');
}
else
{
    $('#validate_ip').text('Valid IP');
}
```

> 2. how can I style the text so that Valid IP appears in green and Invalid IP appears in red?

Create a CSS file which contain classes like

```
.valid
{
    color: #00ff00; /* green */
}

.invalid
{
    color: #ff0000; /* red */
}
```

Then you can simply add the classes with jQuery:

```
if (!pattern.test(ip))
{
    $('#validate_ip').text('Not Valid IP');
    $('#validate_ip').addClass('valid');
}
else
{
    $('#validate_ip').text('Valid IP');
    $('#validate_ip').addClass('invalid');
}
```

Comment: You could use chaining like `$('#validate_ip').text('Not Valid IP').removeClass().addClass('valid');`

Comment: @A.V True, but I guess that the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) applies when uncertain of OP's experience with the matter.

Comment: This is a CGI webpage, so the addresses are parsed out of a file as the webpage loads.

Comment: @Jonast92 does this change the implementation of the `ready` call?

Comment: @DustinCook You should be able to parse the result from the file in the .ready call, give it a try and tell us how it goes.

Comment: @Jonast92 I have been trying with no luck, I wonder if there is a call to just check the validation?  As right now, it is only checked on edit of the text box.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2:

Create a class valid and a class invalid, add the class with jquery by doing this:

```
$('.sn').addClass('valid');

$('.sn').addClass('invalid');
```

in the style define:

```
.valid{
  border:thin solid green;
}

.invalid{
  border:thin solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, but I decided to go with the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help.

I modified your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r5aeus62/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pattern = /\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/;
  x = 46;

  var ip = $('.ip').val();
  var sn = $('.sn').val();
  var br = $('.br').val();
  var nt = $('.nt').val();
  var gw = $('.gw').val();

  if (!pattern.test(ip)) {
     $('#validate_ip').text('Invalid IP');
     $('#validate_ip').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
     $('#validate_ip').text('Valid IP');
     $('#validate_ip').removeClass().addClass('valid');
  }

  if (!pattern.test(sn)) {
     $('#validate_sn').text('Invalid IP');
     $('#validate_sn').removeClass().addClass('invalid');
  } else {
     $('#validate_sn').text('Valid IP');
     $('#validate_sn').removeClass().addClass('valid');
  }

  if (!pattern.test(br)) {
     $('#validate_br').text('Invalid IP');
     $('#validate_br').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
     $('#validate_br').text('Valid IP');
     $('#validate_br').removeClass().addClass('valid');
  }

  if (!pattern.test(nt)) {
     $('#validate_nt').text('Invalid IP');
     $('#validate_ip').removeClass().addClass('invalid');
  } else {
     $('#validate_nt').text('Valid IP');
     $('#validate_nt').removeClass().addClass('valid');
  }

  if (!pattern.test(gw)) {
     $('#validate_gw').text('Invalid IP');
     $('#validate_gw').removeClass().addClass('invalid');
  } else {
     $('#validate_gw').text('Valid IP');
     $('#validate_gw').removeClass().addClass('valid');
}
```

Just look on the fiddle for the whole code.

Happy Coding :D